# html2canvas not working properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, heroku, paperclip

I have used html2canvas to convert the div to canvas and used toDataURL() to convert that to image. After that image is created that is uploaded via paperclip and in development mode it is saved in local storage while in production mode that is uploaded to AWS. The problem here is the saved image, in development the image is displayed as the div whereas in the production the created image is not as the one in the development.
This is the js file.

```
 $(function() {
        $("#campaign_submit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').waitMe({ effect : 'bounce', text : 'Loading'});
            $('#price').val($('#amount').val());
            html2canvas($("#containertoimage"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    theCanvas = canvas;
                    //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
                    if (img.length > 10)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/campaigns/image",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: {img_data: img},
                            success: function(resp){
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: '/campaigns/create_campaign',
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: $("#new_campaign").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                                    success: function(data)
                                    {
                                        window.location="/campaigns/"+data.url
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            ,
                            error: function(resp){
                                 }
                            });
                    }
                    //$('#svg_data_front').val(img);
                }
            });
            });
        });
```

this is the method where image is created

```
 def image
    name = Time.now.to_i
    session[:filename] = name
    data = params[:img_data]
    image_data = Base64.decode64(data['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])
    File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/#{name}.jpg", 'wb') do |f|
     f.write image_data
     link = "#{Rails.root}/public/#{name}.jpg"
      respond_to do |format|
           format.json { render :json => {success: true, file_link: link} }
      end
     end
  end
```

this is the method where the image is saved to the model

```
def create_campaign
    @campaign = current_user.campaigns.build(campaign_params)
    if @campaign.save
      @campaign.update_attributes(:image => File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/#{session[:filename]}.jpg"))
      session[:filename] = nil
      flash[:success] = "Campaign successfully created"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => {success: true, url: @campaign.url} }
      end

    else
      @master_product = MasterProduct.all
      @product_types = MasterProduct.distinct_product_type
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```